# Python - adding new key:value pairs to dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, cad, step

I am currently trying to extract some data from a file which has this kind of format:

```
#12 = ADVANCED_FACE ( 'NONE', ( #194 ), #326, .F. ) ;
...
#159 = EDGE_LOOP ( 'NONE', ( #21, #124, #264, #145 ) ) ;
...
#194 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE', #159, .T. ) ;
...
#326 = PLANE ( 'NONE',  #352 ) ;
```

I have used the following code to search for ADVANCED_FACEs and add them to a dictionary like so:

```
    DoL = {}

    #search for advanced faces and extract IDs
    faces_txt = re.findall(r'#(\d+) = ADVANCED_FACE.*;', text)
    faces = [int(face) for face in faces_txt]

    #append advanced face IDs to dict
    for i, faceId in enumerate(faces):
        DoL.update({"Face{}".format(i): {'AdvancedFace': [faceId]}})
```

This finds all of the ADVANCED_FACES and creates an output like this:

```
Face0 = {'AdvancedFace': [12]}
Face1 = {'AdvancedFace': [73]}
Face2 = {'AdvancedFace': [99]}
Face3 = {'AdvancedFace': [131]}
Face4 = {'AdvancedFace': [181]}
Face5 = {'AdvancedFace': [214]}
Face6 = {'AdvancedFace': [244]}
Face7 = {'AdvancedFace': [273]}
Face8 = {'AdvancedFace': [330]}
Face9 = {'AdvancedFace': [358]}
```

Now I need to find all of the FACE_OUTER_BOUNDs and add them to the dictionary in a similar fashion so the output would look like:

```
Face0 = {'AdvancedFace': [12], 'FaceOuterBound': [194]}
Face1 = {'AdvancedFace': [73], 'FaceOuterBound': [53]}
...
```

I tried using the following method but it throws an error saying 'dict' has no attribute 'append'.

```
#extract face outer bound IDs from advanced face strings
fob_txt = re.findall(r'ADVANCED_FACE.{13}#(\d+).*;', text)
fobs = [int(fob) for fob in fob_txt]

#append face outer bound IDs to dict
for i, fobId in enumerate(fobs):
    DoL["Face{}".format(i)].append({'FaceOuterBounds': (fobId)})
```

Comment: Apparently `DoL["Face{}".format(i)]` evaluates to a dictionary. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm pretty new to programming in general as this is part of my final year project at uni. So still just getting to grips with it atm.

Comment: Is it your intent to have dictionaries in DOL, or is it supposed to contain lists?

Comment: `DoL["Face{}".format(i)]["FaceOuterBounds"] = fobId` should do it

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes my intention is to have dictionaries in DoL. This is so I can access the information within each 'Face' by calling upon a specific key such as 'advancedface', 'faceouterbound' etc...

Comment: @DarrenTaggart You can't `append` to dictionaries though, as the error says. Dictionaries have key/value pairs, whereas `append` just adds values. It's been awhile since I've used Python, so I can't remember what it uses to update its dictionaries, but that's your problem.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah I understand where I have gone wrong now. Thankfully Jose provided a method that has worked and produced the desire output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why not doing ?
DoL["Face{}".format(i)].update({'FaceOuterBounds': [fobId]})

maybe I missunderstand the question...